# Controlling Settings in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, rest, configuration, web-config

I have a website that is mainly based on JavaScript. It uses a REST Service. I have the REST Service URL's hard coded in the JavaScript page. The URL's will change from PROD to testing. Every time I deploy this site to a different environment,  I need to go and update the .JS file. What is the best way to manage these? is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the URL of the current page the JS is loaded in with `location.href`. Using that and some string manipulation you can dynamically create those RESTful URLs.

Answer (score 1):

I usually segregate those addresses and other deployment sensitive values into a separate a script block that is generated by the server at run-time.

Example: (ASP.NET MVC here but could be any language/framework)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pageOptions =
    {
        "detailsDataUrl": '@Url.Action("LoadDetail", "Contact")',
        "applicationBase": '@Url.Content("~")'
    };
</script>
```

You could alternately have multiple versions of one file with just this sort of data and part of your deploy process is to deploy the environment's version.

Update: K. Scott Allen did a very nice post on the different options for passing data from your server code to your javascript code, which this is just one example of.  You can read it [here](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2012/08/28/giving-data-to-javascript.aspx). In particular he mentions a library called [NGON](https://github.com/brooklynDev/NGon) that formalizes the above pattern and adds some handy bells and whistles. I have added it to a couple of projects and find it very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone does it a bit differently, but typically this is done using a build system.  During a build, there is an environment variable on the server doing the build, with a value like "prod" or "qa" or "dev". When the web app components are built, one step involves replacing tokens you put in your files with values appropriate for the environment.

Note if you use relative paths for your restful endpoints, you don't need to do this.  You should only need to do this if you need to change host/protocol/port info.  Which sucks.  Might be better to know which environment you are testing and use /etc/hosts to map standard urls to environment specific ones.  For example, if you app uses

`www.myapp.com`

your could setup an environment that maps that url to `qa.myapp.com:80`.  You would use scripts to manage changing the hosts files for whatever environment you want.